# How do I make a list of agent variables?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make my model compatible with an interface framework that can't handle the csvs I normally export to, and requires lists. What I need to do, specifically, is export a list of lists of variables associated with each of a certain breed of agent.

Ideally:

`set master-list (foreach person set traits-list list (who) (color) (heading) (xcor) (ycor) (etc...))`

But the primary issue I'm having is that after the first two variables set up in the `set traits-list list (items)` way, it starts throwing up errors on any subsequent variables. I can just `lput` each individual variable, but that seems like a really unnecessarily messy way to set it up. Am I missing something?

I've tried seeing if it's the individual variable that's the issue, but the error persists no matter what the third variable is.

If anyone wants to look at the complete code in question, I'm trying to make https://github.com/efyoungud/stationfire work with https://github.com/hlynka-a/SRTI.

Comment: Could you just use `of` to get the list of lists you're looking for?  `set master-list [(list who color heading xcor ycor)] of person`

Comment: Jasper's code looks correct to me. except one thing, it should be `of people` not `of person` (the model has `breed [people person]`)

Comment: The error is because you need a bracket at the beginning  of a list with more than two items (that is `(list` not `list`). Without the bracket, NetLogo expects two items only and is therefore throwing an error for longer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JenB had the answer with needing the bracket.

Final, functional code:

````
 ask people [ foreach [self] of people [
  set traits-list (list (who) (color) (heading)(xcor)(ycor)(shape)(breed)(hidden?)(size) (alarmed?) (age)(visited?)(group-number) (group-type) (group-constant)(speed) (leadership-quality) (leader) (goal) (energy)(speed-limit)
  )]] ; doesn't include next-desired-patch or path because that's calculated each step and doesn't need to be exported
  set master-list [traits-list] of people
end ```
````

Comment: you might want to try Jasper's version though, `of` is much better than `foreach [self]`